# Measure graph angle with Cytoscape js

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I'm using Cyotscape js to display large graph to users and allow them to do some operations with it (finding paths etc). Nodes are fixed with coordinates and as a result edge lengths are known&fixed as well.

Let's say somewhere on the selected path I have nodes following as **A -> B -> C** and the **edge AB** with **edge BC** forms **an angle of less then 90°**. **I would like a script to be able to determine that, measure the angle and inform the user or do some automated stuff.**

- Is there a built-in function that I'm not aware that can be used in
  this case?
- Is there any algorithm that I can use to build my own function to
  determine the angle? (probably relying on the node coordinates?)

Thank you for your precious time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have known node positions -- and hence edge lengths.  Three points (in this case, nodes) form a triangle.  So, you can simply use [trigonometry (Law of Cosines)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to calculate angles.

Comment: Thanks for leading the way! The theory worked out with javascript [Math.atan2](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_atan2.asp) as `deltax = x2-x1;deltay = y2-y1;` `var rad = Math.atan2(deltay,deltax)` then multiplied the resulting radian `rad*(180/Math.PI)` (as I combined from multiple SO threads).  I was first confused as the Math.atan2 gave the angle relative to X plan. The result is great anyway!