# Circle Layout node angles cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

How can i get the angle of each node with the center of the circumference in cytoscape using circle layout?
Visual example:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+angle*+cytoscape+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913715/measure-graph-angle-with-cytoscape-js

Comment: I think i can't use it because the edges are not conected to the center of the graph

Comment: The point is that i think it has to be a property that "represents" the "angle" of each node, but i cant find it

Comment: Which is why I did not hammer close it

Comment: which angle do you need? You can just calculate them using `sourceEndPoint` and `targetEndPoint` methods of edges just check the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step to get the angle of the node, get the center of the circumference
So i get 3 points of the 3rd first nodes to get it:

```
AX= cy.nodes()[0]._private.position.x   
AY= cy.nodes()[0]._private.position.y   
BX= cy.nodes()[1]._private.position.x   
BY= cy.nodes()[1]._private.position.y   
CX= cy.nodes()[2]._private.position.x   
CY= cy.nodes()[2]._private.position.y   

var yDelta_a = BY - AY 
var xDelta_a = BX - AX; 
var yDelta_b = CY - BY; 
var xDelta_b = CX - BX;
var aSlope = yDelta_a / xDelta_a; 
var bSlope = yDelta_b / xDelta_b;

//Get center circumference
coordCentroCircunferenciaX = (aSlope*bSlope*(AY - CY) + bSlope*(AX + BX) - aSlope*(BX+CX) )/(2* (bSlope-aSlope) );
coordCentroCircunferenciaY = -1*(coordCentroCircunferenciaX- (AX+BX)/2)/aSlope +  (AY+BY)/2;
```

Then iterate through the nodes getting the angles:

```
for (i = 1;i< cy.nodes().length; i=i+1) { //starts nodes loop
    let nodo=cy.nodes()[i];
    array.push(nodo._private.data.name);

    //get the node position(x,y)
    nodox=nodo._private.position.x
    nodoy=nodo._private.position.y
```

Now with 3 points: center circumference , node position and another point in the x axis

```
C = { x: coordCentroCircunferenciaX, y: coordCentroCircunferenciaY };
A = { x: nodox, y: 0 };
B = { x: nodox,y:nodoy  };
```

Then i get the angle with this function:

```
function find_angle(A,B,C) {
    var AB = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x-A.x,2)+ Math.pow(B.y-A.y,2));    
    var BC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(B.x-C.x,2)+ Math.pow(B.y-C.y,2)); 
    var AC = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(C.x-A.x,2)+ Math.pow(C.y-A.y,2));
    return Math.acos((BC*BC+AB*AB-AC*AC)/(2*BC*AB))*(180/Math.PI);   
}
```

Finally this is the angle with the center of the circumference:

```
let angulo=Math.round(find_angle(A,B,C))
```

So with this angle i can get this effect to rotate node labels:

[image]